# $.ajax() call function from other document

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the index.php with a $.ajax()-function that runs a php script and displays the result

```
<script>
function loadPage(file) {
$.ajax(...)
...
}
// Runs php files where I display something (echo "...";)
</script>
```

Now I call this function from index.php

```
<button onclick="loadPage('pageToLoad.php')">Click</button>
```

It runs 'pageToLoad.php' which outputs the following on the index.php (in a `<div>`)

```
Page loaded. <button onclick="loadPage('anotherPageToLoad.php')">Click here again</button>
```

If you click on "click here again", the `loadPage()` function should be called again to load another page. But it doesn't work.

Bizarrely, That following works:
I include in index.php another file (via PHP `include()`), let's call it page2.php. When I call `loadPage(pageToLoad.php)` from page2.php, the `onClick`-Event from 'pageToLoad.php' works.

Do you know, why? And how I can solve that problem?

Comment: "But it doesn't work." Which means? Check your console/network tab, any 404 error?

Comment: Are ther any errors, when you hit the button? dose the page's that are loaded generating only this output?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to check the console :) 

Somehow, my program didn't upload the file which I wanted to load with `loadPage()`. Now it works.

Thank you guys